# Using '+' and '-' with numbers

Tags: science

The convention for units is to leave a space after the number, for example, 'the average temperature of the human body is 37.0 °C.'

But what if I need to explicitly state whether a number is positive or negative - do I use a space after the sign?

Would I write:

> Set your refrigerator to + 4 °C.

or

> Set your refrigerator to +4 °C.

Comment: It does look a lot cleaner without the space.

Comment: This is not an "English grammar" issue, just a matter of typography.  Generally it works best to have no space between the sign and the first numerical digit.

Comment: Also, I'd say it's unusual and even awkward to explicitly include the + sign. Numbers are positive by default. I'd only include the + sign in the case that there's a meaningful risk of ambiguity (eg on devices that are most frequently set to negative temps), or a risk that some prankster will pencil in a - sign unless you fill in the space.

Comment: @DanBron, I agree with you - perhaps it was a poor example. My actual use case involves positive and negative use around zero, i.e., compass directions where East is -90 (or - 90) and West is +90 (or + 90). There is some real ambiguity here and statements have to explicitly include number signs as different reference frames exist.

Comment: Also: if you use a space, make sure it is a non-breaking space.  You do not want "4" at the end of one line, and "°C" at the beginning of the next.

Comment: Signs should be considered part of the number, so definitely no space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every technical writing style guide that I have seen that addresses the issue says to leave no space between numerals and mathematical symbols used as modifiers or adjectives.  A few examples include:

Use a space “Before but not after + - ± ... when used as adjectives.”  (*Mathematics into Type: Updated Edition*, 1999, American Mathematical Society, p. 39, §3.1.3c.)

“When mathematical symbols are used as adjectives, that is, with one number that is not part of a mathematical operation, do not leave a space between the symbol and the number.”  (*The ACS Style Guide*, 3d ed, 2006, American Chemical Society, p. 215)  [The listed examples include ±, >, <, and %.]

“Leave no space after mathematical operators used as adjectives”  (*The ACS Style Guide*, 3d ed, 2006, American Chemical Society, p. 219)

“Generally, close up a number and a non alphabetic [math] symbol, whether the symbol precedes or follows the number (except if the symbol is being used as a mathematical operator).”  (*Scientific Style and Format*, 7th ed, 2006, Cambridge University Press, p. 146)

“When these [mathematical] symbols are modifying a number rather than serving as operators, close them up to the numeral that follows or write them out.”  (*Scientific Style and Format*, 7th ed, 2006, Cambridge University Press, p. 159)

“The signs +, -,  ±, ×, and ÷, etc., are closed against accompanying figures and symbols.”  (*U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual*, 2008, p. 259, Rule 10.2)

Comment: +1 Good answer. Do you have online references to any of these documents?

Comment: Thanks for the references. I intuitively use the close form because the sign seems to 'belong to the number'. For the same reason, I use the close form with ratio expressions such as '%' or '°'. they also seem to 'belong to the number'.

Comment: Also, I just added the publisher to the CUP publications in an edit to your answer to highlight the use of both British and American English references. Glad you used both for a more objective answer.

Comment: Mathematics into Type can be found at:  ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf
The GPO Style Manual can be viewed at:  https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008.pdf The ACS Style Guide can be found online, but I suspect the copies I viewed are not legal and I will not list them.